# Switching the first element with the last one in a loop

Tags: r, algorithm, switch-statement, permute

Is there a function in R which switches the first element with the last one in a vector? I have a for loop which need that reordering. From:

```
months = seq(1:12)
[1]  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11 12
```

I would like to have:

```
[1]  12 1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11
```

and then again:

```
[1]  11 12  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10
```

...
until the 12th position.

Comment: What's the final desired ouput? The same as the original input?

Comment: You should have either `1:12`, `seq(1,12)`, or `seq(12)` in your code but not `seq(1:12)`

Comment: @MaratTalipov technically, `seq(1:12)` is fine, if overkill & redundant, because of the non-standard way that `seq` works. `seq(1:12)` equates to `seq(along.with = 1:12)`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm afraid that you have to come up with a home-made function, something like this one:

```
rotate <- function(v,i=1) {
  i <- i %% length(v)
  if (i==0) return(v)
  v[c(seq(i+1,length(v)),seq(i))]
}
```

Couple of examples:

```
v <- seq(12)
rotate(v,1)
# [1]  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11 12  1

rotate(v,-1)
# [1] 12  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11
```

Answer (score 4):

If you need a matrix output

```
 cbind(c(months),embed(c(months, months), 12)[-13,-12])
 #       [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8] [,9] [,10] [,11] [,12]
 # [1,]    1   12   11   10    9    8    7    6    5     4     3     2
 # [2,]    2    1   12   11   10    9    8    7    6     5     4     3
 # [3,]    3    2    1   12   11   10    9    8    7     6     5     4
 # [4,]    4    3    2    1   12   11   10    9    8     7     6     5
 # [5,]    5    4    3    2    1   12   11   10    9     8     7     6
 # [6,]    6    5    4    3    2    1   12   11   10     9     8     7
 # [7,]    7    6    5    4    3    2    1   12   11    10     9     8
 # [8,]    8    7    6    5    4    3    2    1   12    11    10     9
 # [9,]    9    8    7    6    5    4    3    2    1    12    11    10
 #[10,]   10    9    8    7    6    5    4    3    2     1    12    11
 #[11,]   11   10    9    8    7    6    5    4    3     2     1    12
 #[12,]   12   11   10    9    8    7    6    5    4     3     2     1
```

Or another approached suggested by @Marat Talipov

```
 z <- length(months)
 i <- rep(seq(z),z) + rep(seq(z),each=z) - 1
 matrix(months[ifelse(i>z,i-z,i)],ncol=z)
```

Comment: Another approach to obtain matrix: `z <- length(months); i <- rep(seq(z),z) + rep(seq(z),each=z) - 1; matrix(months[ifelse(i>z,i-z,i)],ncol=z)`

Comment: No, because it produces symmetric matrix, in which the first row contains the original vector, and every subsequent row rotates the previous row to the left by one position.

Comment: Oh, I've just noticed that your solution not only rotates but also reverses the original vector (e.g. see the last row of your sample output).

Comment: @MaratTalipov I was looking through the columns instead of the rows.

Answer (score 2):

You can also use `tail` and `head` functions:

```
x = c(tail(x,n), head(x,-n))
```

and modify `n` to rotate `n` times

Answer (score 2):

The **permute** package can do this for you:

```
ap <- allPerms(length(months),
               control = how(within = Within(type = "series"),
                             observed = TRUE))
ap[rev(seq_len(nrow(ap))), ]
```

(because of the way `allPerms()` does its work, we need to reverse the order of the rows, which is what the last line does.)

This gives:

```
> ap[rev(seq_len(nrow(ap))), ]
      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8] [,9] [,10] [,11] [,12]
 [1,]    1    2    3    4    5    6    7    8    9    10    11    12
 [2,]   12    1    2    3    4    5    6    7    8     9    10    11
 [3,]   11   12    1    2    3    4    5    6    7     8     9    10
 [4,]   10   11   12    1    2    3    4    5    6     7     8     9
 [5,]    9   10   11   12    1    2    3    4    5     6     7     8
 [6,]    8    9   10   11   12    1    2    3    4     5     6     7
 [7,]    7    8    9   10   11   12    1    2    3     4     5     6
 [8,]    6    7    8    9   10   11   12    1    2     3     4     5
 [9,]    5    6    7    8    9   10   11   12    1     2     3     4
[10,]    4    5    6    7    8    9   10   11   12     1     2     3
[11,]    3    4    5    6    7    8    9   10   11    12     1     2
[12,]    2    3    4    5    6    7    8    9   10    11    12     1
```

Technically this only works because `months` is the vector `1:12` and `allPerms()` returns a permutation matrix of the indices of the thing you want permuted. For different inputs, use `ap` to index into the thing you want to permute

```
perms <- ap
perms[] <- months[ap[rev(seq_len(nrow(ap))), ]]
perms
```